# Confusion about os.path.isfile()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a rather small script using python3 (Note this isn't actual code but does the same loop)

```
downloads = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Downloads")
for _, dirs, files in os.walk(downloads):
    for dir in dirs:
       for file in files:
           print(file) # breakpoint at this line
```

My confusion is while debugging this in vscode I'm getting the following using the debug console

```
type(file)
<class 'str'>
os.path.isfile(file)
True
file
'.DS_Store'

type(file)
<class 'str'>
os.path.isfile(file)
True
file
'.localized'

type(file)
<class 'str'>
os.path.isfile(file)
False
file
'my_expressvpn_switzerland_udp.ovpn'
```

Why does the last file make `os.path.isfile()` return false?

Comment: What is it? A directory? A regular file?

Comment: it's a file. You use it to make an open vpn connection.